# $operations = Operation::findOrFail(2)->get(); return 6 results

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the operation that as PK id = 2

```
$operations = Operation::findOrFail(2)->get();
```

This line should do the trick, but I get all my 6 operations as result...

Off course, my other 5 has ID value from 1 to 6, they doesn't match.

I checked Operation is a model with no custom config, and Operation table has been created by migration and has ID as PK...

Off course, I could change it with another eloquent query, but this should work and I would love to know why it is failing.

What am I missing ?

Comment: `$operations = Operation::findOrFail(2);` it will give you as model instance. Where `get()` gives you a collection. So delete the `get()`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `->get()` it will should be

`$operations = Operation::with('meters')->findOrFail(2);`

`get()` gives you a collection which is all data of `Operation` to get single instace you should remove `get()`

Comment: Yes, indeed, my problem is I must add ->with('meters') to it, so I need to have Eloquent Builder, not the ->get() result

Comment: Solution is: $operations = Operation::with('meters')->findOrFail(2);